# QwtPlotCurve with arrow / QwtPainter

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I want to draw a QwtCurve with arrow at the end of the curve. After searching a long time, I didn't find a easy way to do that. So I thought about creating a class `QwtPlotArrow` that inherits from `QwtPlotCurve`.

I override the `drawCurve()` function of `QwtPlotCurve` and tried to use the `QwtPainter::drawLine()` function to draw a line on my plot. I am doing that like this:

```cpp
QwtPainter::drawLine(painter, 2, 2, -2, -2);
```

At the end of the override function I call

```cpp
QwtPlotCurve::drawCurve(painter, style, xMap, yMap, canvasRect, from, to);
```

to execude the `drawCurve()` function of `QwtPlotCurve`.

Most things are working fine. The `drawCurve()` function of `QwtPlotArrow` is called and even the `drawCurve()` function of `QwtPlotCurve` is executed afterwards. But the line form (2,2) to (-2,-2) is not drawn on the plot.

That means, that I am dooing something wrong with this command:

```cpp
QwtPainter::drawLine(painter, 2, 2, -2, -2);
```

This command does not paint the line to the plot. Even in the source code of `QwtPlotCurve` I couldn't find how the lines are drawn. For me it looks like the command above is the right one.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think the problem is, that the coordinates have to be maped to the plot. I still don't know how to do that with

```cpp
QwtPainter::drawLine(QPainter, 2, 2, -2, -2);
```

but you can do that with

```cpp
QwtPainter::drawPolyline()
```

Therefore you have to create an `QwtPointSeriesData` object. You can mapp it to the plot with an `QwtPointMapper` object.

Example:

```cpp
void QwtPlotArrow::drawCurve(QPainter *painter, int style, const QwtScaleMap &xMap, const QwtScaleMap &yMap, const QRectF &canvasRect, int from, int to) const
{
    QwtPointSeriesData* mySeries = new QwtPointSeriesData();
    mySeries->setSamples(QVector<QPointF>() << QPointF(2, 2) << QPointF(-2, -2);

    QwtPainter::drawPolyline(painter, QwtPointMapper().toPolygonF(xMap, yMap, mySeries, from, to));

    //Don't forget to execute the drawCurve function from QwtPlotCurve
    QwtPlotCurve::drawCurve(painter, style, xMap, yMap, canvasRect, from, to);
}
```